# why does it fail to send 'post request' and change to 'get method' in chrome?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, frontend

I am a new programmer in fore-end and recently i am learning Vue.I meet a problem.The code below shows i want to add function that will send a 'post request' to backend.

```
<el-button style="width: 50%;box-shadow: black 0px 0px 5px;" @click="trim"></el-button>
methods:{
trim: function () {
      this.$axios({
        methods:'post',
        url:'/trim'
      }).then(response=>{
        alert('success!')
      }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
        return alert('failed to accepted trim signal!')
      })
    },
},
```

The back-end code:

```
/*trim.js file*/
/*The code to deal the post request*/
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('server successed to accept trim post!')
})

module.exports = router
```

...

```
/*The app.js file*/
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var multer = require('multer');
var cors = require('cors')

var trim=require('./routes/trim.js')

app.use('/trim/',trim)

app.listen(8081,() => {
  console.log('server running,port:8081');
})
```

When i run it and click the buttom,the back-end shows it do not accept the request.And the chome shows the fore-end  sends a 'get request'.But it is definitely 'post request' in code.

[image: chome screenshot]

But when i change it to 'get request',it works.I want know would it happen and how can i make 'post request' works?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace  `methods:'post'` with `method:'post'`

Or maybe use `axios.post()` instead.

Comment: oh yeah.How stupid am I to make a mistake like this low level problem!Thank you.Have a good day!

Comment: You're welcome. I usually make common mistakes like that too.